# Couldn't find Comment without an ID - polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The error appears when I try to submit a comment. - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController#index - I followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) and [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) tutorial

the URL is:

```
.../articles/1/comments
```

comments_controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_comment
 before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:new]

def index
  @commentable = load_commentable
  @comments = @commentable.comments
end

...

 def create
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user

 if @comment.save
  redirect_to @comment, notice: "Comment created."
 else
  render :new
 end
end

....

private

def load_commentable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
  @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end

def set_comment
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end
....
```

[Full trace:](http://justpaste.it/exca)

Comment: Can you share the full error stacktrace in the question, it would be helpful to debug.

Comment: See my answer and also take a note of `UPDATE` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the stacktrace, error is appearing on `set_comment` method.

You must be having a callback `before_action` on  `set_comment` which should not be there for `index` action. You should restrict that to only relevant actions.

For example:

```
before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

So that this callback would `only` be invoked for `show, edit, update and destroy` actions.

**UPDATE**

Currently callback is set as `before_action :set_comment` without any restrictions so it will be invoked before each and every action. So, update it as suggested above.